# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to stop service Intent?

Tags: android, service

I want kill another app's server by ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo in third app.
eg,some app's service I want keep alive,else service(NOT fit for Service START_STICK) will be killed.
here is my code:

```
 ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List killapplist = actManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

            List killservicelist = actManager.getRunningServices(100);

            for (Object aKillapplist : killapplist) {

                ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo localRunningAppProcessInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)
                        aKillapplist;

                String appname = localRunningAppProcessInfo.processName;

                if (localRunningAppProcessInfo.pkgList != null) {

                    for (Object aKillservicelist : killservicelist) {
                        ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo localRunningServiceInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo) aKillservicelist;
  //some condition start
                        try {
                            Intent intentstop = new Intent();

                            intentstop.setComponent(localRunningServiceInfo.service);
                            mContext.stopService(intentstop);
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
 //some condition end
                    }

                }

            }

        } else {
            throw new MyException("kill list is empty");
        }
```

then always get warn msg

```
WARN/ActivityManager(363): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo
WARN/System.err(5992): java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to stop service Intent
```

is the problem of sys signature ?
I used some permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
```

how to fix it? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the permissions `"android.permission.SHUTDOWN"` and `"android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"` unless your package is signed with system certificate. Having the permission `"android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"` will allow you to kill only your processes.

Comment: In Android.mk file of your application you need to add LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform