# Closing APK installation view programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, apk

[image]In My application I am installing another application using APK file of another application.
I am using below code for the same:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File( "sdcard/"+objApp.strApkPath)),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to close that view of installation after its done programmatically.Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would the user want this?

Comment: Also, please do not hardcode `sdcard/`, as it is wrong on the majority of Android devices. Please use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` on `Environment` if you have to get to the root of external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare : this is application requirement also thanks for guiding for storage location but above is sample code. My actual question is different. Please help in it.

Comment: "this is application requirement" -- then whoever made this "requirement" needs to be fired.

Comment: Did get a solution to this? I also have same problem?

Comment: No I didn't got any solution :(

Answer (score 0):

After  `startActivity()` call `finish()`

Comment: then try this.finish(); or this.MainClass.finish();

Comment: I want to close above window shown in image and not my activity.

Comment: Try This

    'ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService("activity");
    Method forceStopPackage;                
    forceStopPackage =am.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("forceStopPackage",String.class);
    forceStopPackage.setAccessible(true);
    forceStopPackage.invoke(am, pkg);'
In manifest file add this

'<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>'

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiasti: Thanks a lot for helping me.
I have replaced pkg with "com.android.packageinstaller" don't know why but its giving me null exception without any more information after invoke method call. Any idea?

Comment: @PoojaBohora, oh please try other package name whether that line is works or not. put log or debug your app. easily you find out your problem.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiastic :While adding required permission I got security exception while searching on it I got this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340784/java-lang-securityexception-not-allowed-to-stop-service-intent
But I am still not able to get how to add it? Had you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

please add  Android.mk file of your application you need to add LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform